# Implemented unit test for EntityManager spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to implement unit test for a class using `EntityManager`

```
public class A {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public <T> TypedQuery<T> createTypedQuery(String queryString, Class<T> type) {
        return entityManager.createQuery(queryString, type);
    }

}
```

How do I implement unit test for method createTypedQuery

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a constructor and set @PersistenceContest annotations next to it.

```
@PersistenceContext
public A(EntityManager entityManager) {
     this.entityManager = entityManager
}
```

Create an object in the test

```
A a = new A(mockEntityManager)
```